# SharePoint throttling

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, throttling

We have a lot of users that use SharePoint and also we use only application token to manage the data. So we send lots of requests and we are facing throttling. So the questions are:

1. Are there any possibilities to increase the requests limit?
2. How can I see my current quota/resource usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can not request a limit increase, and Microsoft does not provide any specific information regarding the algorithm they use to decide when or why to begin throttling.

The best option you have is to apply incremental back-off logic to account for throttled calls:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/handle-sharepoint-online-throttling-by-using-exponential-back-off

You have to contact Microsoft support and open a ticket in order to get information regarding which service principals and users are being throttled. An engineer will have to pull the info from their database.

They can not give you specific quota/resource information. The will only tell you how many calls were throttled for a given principal.